# Teradata import error - import complete but no data inserted into columns

Tags: sql, teradata

I am using Teradata's SQL Assistant to load data into a table. File has matching columns with same layout. Any ideas of why this would complete the import but not insert any data into the table?

Here is the SQL for the table and for the insert...

```
CREATE MULTISET TABLE DLAB_MARKETING.ProfileAttributes,
NO FALLBACK,
NO BEFORE JOURNAL,
     NO AFTER JOURNAL,
     CHECKSUM = DEFAULT,
     DEFAULT MERGEBLOCKRATIO
     (
      FullName VARCHAR(50) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC NOT NULL,
      EmailAddress VARCHAR(100) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC NOT NULL,
      FirstName VARCHAR(100) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC,
      LastName VARCHAR(100) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC,
      ZipCode INTEGER,
      StoreNumber INTEGER,
      StoreAddress VARCHAR(100) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC,
      StoreCity VARCHAR(100) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC,
      StoreState CHAR(2) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC,
      StoreZip INTEGER,
      State VARCHAR(25) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC NOT NULL,
      Source_ VARCHAR(75) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC NOT NULL,
      PhoneNumber INTEGER,
      Address1 VARCHAR(150) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC,
      Address2 VARCHAR(150) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC,
      City VARCHAR(100) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC,
      Gender CHAR(1) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC,
      MobilePhone INTEGER,
      CR2StoreIntersection INTEGER,
      CR2StoreCity VARCHAR(100) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC,
      Pet INTEGER,
      ShoppingFrequency INTEGER,
      AgeToddler INTEGER,
      AgeChildren6to17 INTEGER,
      Age25To34 INTEGER,
      Age18To24 INTEGER,
      Age35To44 INTEGER,
      Age45To54 INTEGER,
      AdultApparel INTEGER,
      Age55To64 INTEGER,
      Age65orGreater INTEGER,
      Dog INTEGER,
      Cat INTEGER,
      Groceries INTEGER,
      Snacks INTEGER,
      Cleaning INTEGER,
      Q4NoAnswer INTEGER,
      AgeInfant INTEGER,
      HBA INTEGER,
      Baby INTEGER,
      ChildrenClothing INTEGER,
      Housewares INTEGER,
      Party INTEGER,
      Seasonal INTEGER,
      Toys INTEGER,
      SchoolSupplies INTEGER,
      Cellular INTEGER,
      General INTEGER,
      Ad INTEGER,
      Survey INTEGER,
      Coupon INTEGER,
      Contest INTEGER,
      White INTEGER,
      AA INTEGER,
      AmericanIndian INTEGER,
      Asian INTEGER,
      Hawaiian INTEGER,
      Hispanic INTEGER,
      Other INTEGER,
      Q6NoAnswer INTEGER,
      CR2StoreNumber INTEGER,
      HTMLEmails VARCHAR(100) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC,
      SubscriberKey VARCHAR(125) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC,
      Status VARCHAR(50) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC NOT NULL)
PRIMARY INDEX ( EmailAddress );

INSERT  INTO DLAB_MARKETING.ProfileAttributes
(FullName, EmailAddress, FirstName, LastName, ZipCode, StoreNumber,
        StoreAddress, StoreCity, StoreState, StoreZip, State, Source_,
        PhoneNumber, Address1, Address2, City, Gender, MobilePhone, CR2StoreIntersection,
        CR2StoreCity, Pet, ShoppingFrequency, AgeToddler, AgeChildren6to17,
        Age25To34, Age18To24, Age35To44, Age45To54, AdultApparel, Age55To64,
        Age65orGreater, Dog, Cat, Groceries, Snacks, Cleaning, Q4NoAnswer,
        AgeInfant, HBA, Baby, ChildrenClothing, Housewares, Party, Seasonal,
        Toys, SchoolSupplies, Cellular, General, Ad, Survey, Coupon,
        Contest, White, AA, AmericanIndian, Asian, Hawaiian, Hispanic,
        Other, Q6NoAnswer, CR2StoreNumber, HTMLEmails, SubscriberKey,
        Status)

VALUES  
(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?,
        ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?,
        ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?,
        ?)
```

Comment: Which utility are you using? What does the log show?

Comment: Don't close this question just yet. I think it may be a valid question once it is shaped better.

Answer (score 1):

In the off chance your connection's transaction semantic is defaulting to ANSI instead of Teradata you will need to submit a `COMMIT;` after your `INSERT` statement.

To check your session's transaction semantic:

1. Connect to Teradata
2. `HELP SESSION;`
3. Look for Transaction Semantics. It will be either Teradata or ANSI.

You can also specify the transaction semantics in your ODBC DSN configuration.